# Set the region on creating the Amazon SQS in C#

Tags: c#, cloud, amazon-sqs

I am very new in cloud computing world(including Amazon Web Service), so I have a very simple question:

- How do I set the region of a amazon sqs when I create it? The default region is "US-West (Northern California)".

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

There's a better way to do it now that uses the Amazon.RegionEndpoint class rather than using a url string. The Visual Studio intellisense will give you all the regions.

```
AmazonSQS sqs = AWSClientFactory.CreateAmazonSQSClient(RegionEndpoint.USWest2);
```

Also, you don't need to pass the appConfig["AWSAccessKey"] in the parameters as long as you have it defined in the app.config. It'll find it.

Comment: You can use now something like this new AmazonSQSClient(Amazon.RegionEndpoint.EUWest1);

Answer (score 3):

After a deep research I found the solution:

```
AmazonSQS sqs = AWSClientFactory.CreateAmazonSQSClient(
            appConfig["AWSAccessKey"],
            appConfig["AWSSecretKey"],
            new AmazonSQSConfig().WithServiceURL("The url for wanted region")
            );
```

The regions and urls are:

- Europa, Ireland:   http://eu-west-1.queue.amazonaws.com
- US, Northern California:  http://us-west-1.queue.amazonaws.com
- Asia Pacific, Singapore:  http://ap-southeast-1.queue.amazonaws.com...

Source: http://aws.amazon.com/sqs/faqs/#What_is_the_EU_End-Point